# Change a range of list items into integers in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, range

I have a list. Let's say it's 10 items long. They are all string type list items.  I'm trying to find a short way to change the 3rd through 10th item into an integer type object while leaving the first 2 as strings.
Python 3.3

yeah it wasn't quite working so i tried splitting it into a list of its own and this happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "project1.py", line 10, in <module>

    hList=list(map(int,row[2:]))                       #row is the name of my string list

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.67'
```

I tried printing `hList` and it displayed the first 4 of the 24 in my loop

Comment: It looks like you are actually dealing with float rather than int. Change the call to `list(map(float,row[2:]))`

Comment: If any of the answers helped, please don;t forget to accept it

Answer (score 10):

This can be easily done with slice assignment

```
>>> l = list(map(str, range(10)))
>>> l[2:] = map(int, l[2:])
>>> l
['0', '1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Another way of approaching this problem is to split it as two list, and converting one of them to an integer list.

```
>>> l = list(map(str, range(10)))
>>> l = l[:2] + map(int, l[2:])
>>> l
['0', '1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The difference is, in the later case, you create a new `list` where as in the former in updates the `list` in place

@Ashwini mentioned, Python 3, map returns a map object rather than a list, so you may want to pass it through a `list` call or better make it a list comprehension

```
l[2:] = [int(e) for e in  l[2:]]
```

or

```
l[2:] = list(map(int, l[2:]))
```

Comment: In py3x map() returns a `map` object. so, `l = l[:2] + map(int, l[2:])`  will fail.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I am still stuck with Py2X :-) anyway, I agree its worth mentioning

Comment: Same here, even I hardly ever use 3x. But as the question was tagged with 3x, so, I thought it's worth pointing out.

Comment: The slice assignment works fine in Python3, what should be fixed is the code where you try to add a slice and a `map` object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist[2:] = [int(l) for l in mylist[2:]]

>>> mylist
['0', '1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a rare case when I'd use the index in a loop:

```
In [1]: l = list(map(str, range(10)))

In [2]: l
Out[2]: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

In [3]: for i in range(2, 10):
   ...:     l[i] = int(l[i])
   ...:     

In [4]: l
Out[4]: ['0', '1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or use a slice assignment as Abhijit shows.

Note that if you use a list and ...

1. It's not homogeneous (some items are integers, some are not),
2. Its length is fixed (you know in advance it's 10),

then maybe list isn't the best choice of data structure. Consider using a `tuple` or a `dict` instead. There are some nice extensions of these in the [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html) module, too.

Comment: wow awesome! i have been trying to figure this out for hours. thanks! i would upvote if it let me

Comment: uh oh. it's not working. i used len(list) for the second part of my range. hmmm.  edit:I lied i had 2 lists mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop can do that:

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
new_list = []
for index in range(2, 10): # start at 2 because indexing starts at 0
    my_num = float(my_list[index]) # if the number was not an integer, but a float, it is better to use float(),
    new_list.append(my_num)        # which can handle both floats and integers
print new_list # so you can see the result
```

Output:

```
[3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
```